# Apply Terraform lifecycle ignore_changes to all the resources in the workspace

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-openstack

I would like to apply Terraform lifecycle ignore_changes config to all the resources in the workspace. Instead of doing this individually for every resource, is there any option to define this globally to the workspace so that it will be applicable to all the resources.

**Note**:

- Using Openstack cloud provider so all the resources are related to it.
- Around 100 plus resources available in a workspace

Please clarify.

Comment: Why do you want this? Terraform is designed to manage the full lifecycle of everything it creates and manages. The `ignore_changes` lifecycle block is meant to be used as an escape hatch for when Terraform can't fully manage something for some reason.

Comment: Yes I Agree, when we manage the deployment completely with Terraform. But in my usecase, there are some environments which are already deployed using OpenStack HEAT and it is up and running. Now I wanted them to manage using Terraform. To achieve this, I could able to generate the Terraform state (using Terraform import & custom implementation) but only pending item was not able to get the instance user_data id from Openstack. That's the reason I wanted to add ignore_changes.user_data attribute.

Comment: Another use case: resources can be changed via Azure policy. e.g. tags are added automatically for every resources created in Azure. I am not saying this is best practice (IMHO it is not) but there are some companies that do that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that right now